# How to add user to resource pool in sharepoint 2016 through CSOM C#?

Tags: development, csom, project-server, project-online

Currently the sharepoint is setup in SharePoint permission mode. How do we add a new user to resource pool ? I'm able to add the user to a group using
web.EnsureUser("domainname//abc"). But the user doesn't show up in the resource list until he access the sharepoint site. (PWA site)

I'm updating the owner of the project through my CSOM code.

Comment: why you need to add user to resource pool? Also, the question is tagged for both on-prem and online, please be specific while posting a question, the solution can be difference based on env.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ThinkB4Code . I'm very new to sharepoint, so we have the sharepoint on-premise. Not online. Sorry for the confusion. I want to change the owner of the projects but when i add a user to one of 7 groups in sharepoint. I cannot pick those users when i try to change the owner of the project.

Comment: And this happening only for new users you add to site?

Comment: Yes New users. Once they open the PWA site. I'm able to pick the user as resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on our discussion, I was having the same problem but the problem was slightly different.

**Why this is happening**: When you a add new user to AD, the profile sync job takes some time to pick the newly added user and create the SP UPS entry, and which finally syncs with all site collections and creates entry in UIL. Until the UPS is not available, people picker wont show the user. Now when you add this user to AD groups which are mapped to SPO Groups, they gets the permission, and ensure user method will returns true as well, still people picker dont show the user, since the information is yet not available on UPS/UIL. In our case, we were using SPO so usually it takes b/w 1-4hours to create the UPS.

**Solution we used on SPO**: I created a SP Group (lets say Jump Start SP Group) on root site, which is having only limited read permissions. Ideally this SP group does nothing in regards to permission. Now once the new user is created, we add them directly to jump start group (we used Azure to automate the process). Doing this, force SP to create the UPS for the new user, and now the user is available in people picker.

Since we were using Identity Access Management tool we were able to automate this process. Now for on-prem, you might need to think a bit more on how to automate this process based on your environment setup and process. But simply adding use to site directly will solve people picker issue.

Comment: Thanks @ThinkB4Code